# How to download files recursively from private Bitbucket repository?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, wget

I've uploaded .rpm packages to Download folder under Bitbucket repository.
Then I wanted to download all files located inside that folder.

[image]

Using this command

```
wget --no-check-certificate  -r --user user1 --ask-password https://bitbucket.org/testrepo/ansible-os_k8s/downloads
```

gave me (local machine, no proxy)

```
Reusing existing connection to bitbucket.org:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
Authentication selected: Basic realm="Bitbucket.org HTTP"
Reusing existing connection to bitbucket.org:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2020-02-26 15:36:19 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

Could your guys help
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One option to download is first clone repo and then run this command: git archive --output=./example_repo_archive.tar.gz --format=tar HEAD ./build